How to add event listener to the google form
I am developing an extension for my personal use. It will store the information that I fill in a google form.
The issue I am facing is that the submit button in google forms is actually a span with nested elements and does not actually have a specific button tag.
Additionally I am unable to intercept the submit event
The below code is not working

let forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
forms[0].addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
   ev.preventDefault();

   // Store data locally using FormData

   // submit form after storing data only if form accepted the data

});


After running this in console the event listener is not triggered on clicking the button.
How do I add a submit event to the google form submit or next button ?
I have tried using the preventDefault and returning false in the handler function but still cannot stop the form from submitting when submit button is pressed.

you probably need to intercept the "click" event on the span that acts as a submit button - although, you may not be able to since your handler may run after whatever handler is already added to that span

Event handlers on Google Forms are bound with JsAction via the jsaction property. The parent container for the button looks something like this:
<div
  role="button"
  class="uArJ5e UQuaGc Y5sE8d VkkpIf QvWxOd M9Bg4d"
  jscontroller="VXdfxd"
  jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"
  aria-label="Submit"
></div>

You can clone the button element to get a node that looks similar but has none of the previously attached event handlers and clear the jsaction property to stop the framework from re-registering them.
const submitElement = document.querySelector('[role=button][aria-label=Submit]')

if (submitElement && submitElement.parentNode) {
  const interceptedButton = submitElement.cloneNode(true)
  interceptedButton.setAttribute('jsaction', '')
  submitElement.parentNode.replaceChild(interceptedButton, submitElement)

  interceptedButton.addEventListener("click", ev => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    alert("Click intercepted.")
  });
}

The [aria-label=Submit] property selector works for all locales as only the visible label on the button changes with the user's language setting.
